# copy folder based on cell

Tags: vba, excel

Would it be possible to copy folder to another folder using `EXCEL-VBA`?

example here

[image]

If i entered the v in the example in D9 and fill the target path in E3 then it will copy the folder in E:\DATABASE2012Data2012 along the file inside to the Target folder F:\Workdata

So basically what I need is to input the target path in E3 and just need to insert v in D7 or/and/to D9

Is it possible to do this with `VBA`?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this *Old School Style* by using the Command Interpreter XCOPY command:

```
' VBA Code to open a command window and run XCOPY
Shell Environ("comspec") & " /k xcopy " & Range("E9").text & " " & Range("F9").text & " /s /e /i"
```

so what  that does is open a Command window, and execute the XCOPY command to copy the folder in Range E9 to the new directory specified in F9.

/k - this will keep the Command window open - useful for testing

/c - this will close the command window when it's finished.

There are numerous switches you can use with XCOPY, detailed on [Microsoft - XCOPY Switches](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/289483)

alternatively you could use FILECOPY as detailed on [Ron De Bruin: VBA FileCopy](http://www.rondebruin.nl/folder.htm) and [Ron De Bruin: VBA FolderCopy](http://www.rondebruin.nl/folder.htm#Copy)

if you have Excel 2010-2013, you can use the new [CopyFolder method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264819.aspx)

yet another option is to use the [FILESYSTEMOBJECT - CopyFolder method](http://www.thevbprogrammer.com/Ch06/06-09-FSO.htm) (ex: **FileSystemObject.CopyFolder "c:\mydocuments\letters*", "c:\tempfolder\"**)

HTH

Philip

Comment: Wow thank you... but it seem xcopy wont work since the source folder have \ (backslash) behind it (xcopy say invalid path) so i need to remove all \ behind the directory name and second it doesn't create Data2012 folder inside the workdata folder (it only copy the file and subfolder inside Data2012 folder)... third seem it doesn't support multiple cell range F7:F9 will read more Ron De Bruinand CopyFolder method thx

Comment: I checked XCOPY information, and the /s switch causes it to not copy empty directories. ALSO, if a path has spaces, please SURROUND THE PATH WITH QUOTES...so instead of typing: c:\documents and settings type "c:\documents and settings" ...

Comment: For the Multiple cell range (F7 to F9) you would run the command several times in a loop ... for i=7 to 9 ...use range("F" & i).value ... next